# Calling fzf from nim doesn't show fzfs TUI

Tags: python, tty, nim-lang, fzf

I'm trying to port a small python script of mine to nim. The core is a call to fzf:

```
fzf = subprocess.Popen(["fzf"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = fzf.communicate(some_data)
```

As far as I understand fzf open `/dev/tty` to make its interactions with the user and uses stdin/stdout to communicate with the program which called it. The corrosponding nim code:

```
var p = startProcess(path_to_fzf)
var stream = p.inputStream()
stream.write(some_data)
stream.flush()
```

But in my nim version the fzf TUI does not appear. But input to the terminal is read, because based on my input the correct item is chosen.

I have no idea left why that might be the case. I thought maybe nim creates a PTY with `startProcess` but `/proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr` does not increase, so I think that's not the case. I tried compiling with `-d:useFork` because .. well no idea why that should fix it, and it didn't. As far as I understand fzf/terminal/tty there shouldn't really something be that nim could do to prevent fzf from writing to `/dev/tty`. Or maybe python does something I'm not aware of that triggers fzf to show its TUI?

So my question is how to convince fzf to show its TUI from nim (and why/how it doesn't already).

Comment: Doesn't the second line of that python program set sys.stdout to the fzf process? Hard to tell without the rest of your program. Basically what a TUI does is to read and write from stdin and stdout respectively (and possibly stderr). When you run it as a process these are simply streams in Nim. So in order to allow the TUI to show you must re-direct the stdout of fzf to the stdout of your program, and allow it to take input from stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a proper answer I found the option `poParentStreams` in the `osproc` module. It can be used like this to start a TUI:

```
import osproc

let process = startProcess("htop", options = {poParentStreams, poUsePath})
let eCode = process.waitForExit()
if eCode == 0:
  echo "htop completed successfully"
else:
  echo "htop aborted with error code: " & $eCode
```

@syntonym pointed out in the comments that `fzf` opens `/dev/tty` in order to show the TUI without disrupting the stdin/stdout flow. I'm not entirely sure why this doesn't work in Nim, but a solution is of course to write the result into a named pipe and read out from that, like this:

```
import osproc
import posix
import streams

discard mkfifo("/tmp/fzfoutput", 0o644)
let process = startProcess("echo \"hello\nworld\" | fzf > /tmp/fzfoutput", options = {poUsePath, poEvalCommand, poParentStreams})
var f: File
discard f.open("/tmp/fzfoutput")
echo "Output of fzf:" & f.readLine()
let eCode = process.waitForExit()
if eCode == 0:
  echo "fzf completed successfully"
else:
  echo "fzf aborted with error code: " & $eCode
discard execCmd("rm /tmp/fzfoutput")
```

Comment: Normally programs read and write stdin/stdout to communicate with the user, but fzf uses a clever trick: It opens `/dev/tty` which is always the terminal (and not stdin/stdout which might not be seen by the user, as is here the case). This way fzf can be used in pipes e.g. `find . -name '*.mp3' | fzf | xargs vlc`. But I have no idea why it does not work with my nim code, the python code works as I expect it to work.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you can achieve this. Not entirely sure why it doesn't work in Nim the same way as it does in Python, but this should work.

Comment: Somehow this is not what I hoped for, but if it works it works. I'll wait a day or two if someone knows why the "normal nim version" doesn't work, but if noone appears I'll accept your answer.